# Multiple components/columns of different sizes in UIPickerView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uipickerview

I have a UIPicker view with multiple components/columns. Is it possible for the components to be different sizes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the following...

```
- (CGSize)rowSizeForComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

Simply return the relevant size for each column (component) via this method. Set your view to be the delegate for the picker and implement the above method.

UPDATE: As pointed out by Dave, I picked the wrong method, I meant to specify the one in the delegate...

```
– pickerView:widthForComponent:
```

Comment: -1 this is an instance method on `UIPickerView`, and in order to make this return a non-default value, you'd have to subclass `UIPickerView`.  You should use the `<UIPickerViewDelegate>` method instead.

Comment: Absolutely Dave, I typed the wrong one! Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

[`<UIPickerViewDelegate>` has a method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006924-CH3-SW6) you can optionally implement to define a custom width for a component:

```
- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

Your `UIPickerView` delegate object can implement this to return any number you like.  This number will be used as the `.width` of the struct returned from `-[UIPickerView rowSizeForComponent:]`.

Comment: Great! Is there any way to know what size the picker would've chosen if I didn't implement this method, from inside this delegate method?

Comment: @Yar not directly, no.  You can maybe do it in a round-about way by lying in `-respondsToSelector:` about whether you have this method implemented, loading the pickerView, asking for the `-[UIPickerView widthForComponent:]`, and then storing that. But it'd be a lot of work. :P

Comment: Thanks. Right now choosing something less than 50% of bounds.size.width works, but it doesn't seem like the kind of thing you can depend on.